# Cispr/EU testing: Large Loop Antenna System vs 60cm Loop antenna

Tags: emc, testing

I want to be able to do some pre-testing to EU standards, and I am not able to find clear information regarding the proper test equipment.  From what I've read in an older version of the Cispr15 standard, either the LLAS or the 60cm loop antenna can be used for radiated emissions in the 9 kHz to 30 MHz range.  It also mentions somewhere that the 60cm loop can be used for EUTs > 1.6m in size.

Does that mean that I cannot use the 60cm loop to test to Cispr standards for smaller devices?  Is the 60cm loop at least useful for pre-testing a device before submitting for certification?  If so, what factors should I take into account?

DISCLAIMER: I am not well versed in EM, and am basically training on-the-job.

Comment: From what I remember it's conducted emissions that are done in the 9 kHz to 30 MHz range (not radiated emissions) and, for very sensible reasons.

Comment: I don't have access to the EU standards, so I can't really research what is needed.  All I know is that I have a sample that is failing the Cispr 15 test when performed with the LLAS, but passes (barely) when our local guy (USA) does it with the 60cm loop.  We can't market the product in Europe until we pass that test.  FWIW, it passes the CFR18 with room to spare.

Comment: I'm not familiar with CISPR, I take it this is some manner of lighting/sign application? What document told you that you need this standard, more precisely? Checking the EMC directive list of standards [here](https://ec.europa.eu/growth/single-market/european-standards/harmonised-standards/electromagnetic-compatibility-emc_en) (pdf for download at the bottom), I can't find CISPR 15:2018 - harmonized standards in EU always have the "EN" prefix. It may however be referred to by a listed, harmonized standard in which case it is normative too.

Answer (score 0):

Radiated emissions pre-compliance testing is usually done in the 30MHz to 1GHz range with an LPDA antenna.
[image]
<sub>Source: [Schwarzbeck](http://www.schwarzbeck.de/en/antennas/hybrid-antenna.html)</sub>

Conducted emissions are tested in the lower frequency range. For relatively small products like PCBs there is probably not much of a concern of radiating at low frequencies since the potential antennas on the PCB are way too small for that. The cables are the most likely antennas in the low MHz range.